Create non existing tag with Django-select2
I am using django-select2 to autocomplete a tag field on a model. I would like to let user write any tag in the field, and create it if the tag doesn't exists...
# models.py
class Version(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

class VersionTagWidget(s2forms.ModelSelect2TagWidget):
    search_fields = [
        "nom__icontains",
    ]


class VersionEditViewForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    class Meta:
        model = Version       
        widgets = {
            "tags": VersionTagWidget,

        }

I can autocomplete value (and select in a dynamic dropdown), but if type in a non-existing (in my example, I entered 'DoesNotExist') value and submit the form, I get :
Exception Value:    
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'DoesNotExist'.

I tried a lot of things to solve the pb.... But no clue here...

Have you tried using a ModelChoiceField?

I did try to reproduce the code according to your source... Same result...
